# How to reduce number of colors to 1024 with PIL python

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, quantize

I am trying to reduce number of colors to 1024, but got error
ValueError: bad number of colors

```
img = img.convert('P', palette=Image.ADAPTIVE, colors=1024)
```

or

```
img = img.quantize(256, 0)
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Try `img = img.quantize(colors=256)`

Answer (score 0):

As you can see here from the `PIL.Image` module source code `https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/PIL/Image.html` the documenting comment for the `convert` method states that:

```
 When converting from "RGBA" to "P" without a ``matrix`` argument,
 this passes the operation to :py:meth:`~PIL.Image.Image.quantize`,
 and ``dither`` and ``palette`` are ignored.
```

so the `quantize` method is used for the operation because you didn't provide a `matrix` argument to the convert method and now inside of the `quantize` method the documenting states that:

```
Convert the image to 'P' mode with the specified number
of colors.

:param colors: The desired number of colors, <= 256
```

so the number of colors should be less than or equal to 256 instead a `ValueError` exception will be raised.